# How do I type an emoji in GroupMe with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emoji

[In Skype](http://www.freemake.com/blog/top-10-secret-skype-features/), it looks like I can just encapsulate the emoji name I want in parentheses.

How do I do something like this in GroupMe?

Comment: Are you asking about the web interface for GroupMe? Is there one? If not, I'm afraid your question is off topic here. You should ask on [apple.se], [android.se], or [windowsphone.se] as appropriate.

Comment: Yep, [there is one](http://web.groupme.com). I use it on my Chromebook.